# Problema con un helper en Laravel 6

Tags: composer, laravel-6

estoy con Laravel 6 y creé un helper para que me traiga la ruta de la imagen del usuario. El tema es que la imagen de usuario, puede estar generada por un link externo (el nombre que se almacena en la BD siempre empezará con "https") o un archivo que se almacena en el servidor.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

function userPicture($user_id) {
  $picture = DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', $user_id)
    ->pluck('picture')
    ->first();

  if (Str::startsWith($picture, 'https')) {
      $result = $picture;
  } else {
      $result = '/images/users/' . $picture;
  }

  return ($result);
}
```

Ese es mi helper, lo declaré en el archivo composer.json como dice la documentación y lo llamo desde cualquier vista con la siguiente linea:

```
userPicture($message->user_from)
```

donde `$message->user_from` es el id del usuario que envia un mensaje.
Resulta que ahora quiero subir estas modificaciones al servidor de prueba que ya esta en la nube, pero necesito ejecutar composer dump-autoload pero en el servidor... y no tengo consola... como puedo hacer ?

---

Necesito hacer un composer dump-autoload porque siguiendo la documentación, para registrar el helper tuve que agregar estas lineas al composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Cómo en el servidor no tienes consola supongo que subiste todas las dependencias del proyecto inicialmente. Después de "regenerar" el *autoload* en local deberás sustituir el contenido del directorio de *composer* remoto, por el nuevo, donde estas cargando tu helper. Haz un renombrado del directorio "vendors/composer/" en remoto *por si acaso*, y sube una copia de tu directorio de composer local.

Comment: ahhhh perfecto... solamente el vendor/composer todo lo demas lo puedo dejar como esta... ya estaba pensando en subir todo de nuevo

Comment: mismo sistema si añades alguna dependencia al proyecto, solo que además del directorio de *composer* tendrías que añadir los directorios de la dependencia y dependencias de este creadas o actualizadas.