# Call to undefined function Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy realizando unas practicas de laravel el problema que tengo es que no me llama la funciona que e creado en la carpeta app/helpers.php a lo que he llamado helpers.php la función es la siguiente

```
<?php

 function setActive($routeName)
 {
 return request()->routeIs($routeName) ? 'active' : '';
 }
```

y esa función la mando a llamar en la carpeta resources/views/plantilla.blade.php lo que hace es que cuando este en alguna parte del menú cambie de color el vinculo pero cuando lo pruebo me sale ese error

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="{{ setActive('home') }}"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="{{ setActive('ayuda') }}"><a href="/ayuda">Ayuda</a></li>
        <li class="{{ setActive('contacto') }}"><a href="/contacto">Contacto</a></li>
        <li class="{{ setActive('portfolio') }}"><a href="/portfolio">Portafolio</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Para usar las funciones de helper.php, debes cargarlas en tu aplicación (autoload). ¿Puedes mostrarnos que tienes en tu composer.json en el atributo "autoload"?

Comment: https://send.firefox.com/download/b2399a22c789fb66/#A6Bb9DS5EEehiRtiqrsUsw aquí esta el archivo

Comment: ya lo subir @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: lo siento no sabia que te iba a pedir que descargaras algo, pero ya subi donde menciona el autoload

Comment: Ok, donde dice `"autoload": { ...` agrega el siguiente array `"files": [ "app/helpers.php" ]`, tal cual como está en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/325162/problema-con-un-helper-en-laravel-6). Luego en una terminal corre el comando `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: listo, eres le mejor es que la verdad estoy sacando un curso que compre en una plataforma pero el instructor no explica nada de eso ! o sera por que es una versión un anterior ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108955/discussion-between-ronald-funes-and-porloscerros-).

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ una duda mas digamos si creo otro archivo personalizado también lo tengo que agregar al composer.json de nuevo o ya queda referenciado para las futuras creaciones de archivos en ese aspecto no se si me doy a entender ?

Comment: Si es un archivo sólo con funciones, como es este el caso, sí, tendrás que indicar que lo cargue. Si son clases y están dentro del directorio `/app`, laravel lo hará automáticamente, sólo ten en cuenta de seguir el standard [psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) pues hace poco leí que, aunque actualmente lo hace, ya no lo hará si no sigues ese standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar las funciones de tu archivo de helpers `/app/helper.php`, debes cargarlas en tu aplicación (en tiempo de ejecución). Las funciones de PHP no pueden cargarse automáticamente, entonces deberás indicarle a Laravel que lo haga.

En el archivo [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6e5f40939ce15d731276b2ad6e5fd08057faa79a/composer.json#L35) verás la clave `"autoload"`.

Agrega a ese atributo una clave `"files"` con un array que contenga tu archivo para que Laravel lo cargue y puedas usar sus funciones:

```
// ...
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
// ...
```

Luego en una terminal corre el comando:

```
composer dump-autoload
```